# Re-scaling dimensions of STL files

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I need to put a motor for my robot. I got the mesh from besttechnology.co.jp/modules/knowledge/?BTX050%20Dynamixel%20EX-106%2B ,
but it is on STP format. I opened it with 3D tool and i realiced that his long measure was 65m, when it should be 65mm. Then i scaled it into mm (on 3dtool-> moretools -> rescaling), and convert it into a stl file. I can open this new 3d file with all viewers (3dtool, freecad, meshlab...) but when i load it on my URDF file, the Rviz dont show the figure, and no error appears.. The color material is ok, couse i use it on another link. Some idea?

THX

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111301/re-scaling-dimensions-of-stl-files./) by [cedaone](https://answers.ros.org/users/7991/cedaone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the solution:
bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/275/scale-incorrect-in-atlasurdf-files

---

Originally posted by [cedaone](https://answers.ros.org/users/7991/cedaone/) with karma: 16 on 2013-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0